# Returning a relationships results through static method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to provide an extra static 'find' method on my eloquent model, shown here:

```
public static function findBySku($sku)
{
    // Using new self; provides the same empty collection results
    $instance = new static;

    // Using $instance->sku()->newQuery()->get() also returns the same empty collection
    $results = $instance->sku()->get();

    /*
    * This returns an empty collection, however there are records inside the 
    * relationship database table?
    */
    dd($results);
}
```

So I can use: `Inventory::findBySku($sku);`

Here's the relationship:

```
public function sku()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Stevebauman\Maintenance\Models\InventorySku', 'inventory_id', 'id');
}
```

I know the relationship itself isn't the issue because this returns the results from the database table fine:

```
Inventory::find(1)->sku()->get();
```

Anyone have any ideas why this doesn't work?

I know it could be because I'm calling a non-static method from a static instance, but why would it return a resulting collection without throwing an error?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$sku`? An id or a value of a column in `InventorySku`?

Comment: SKU is a `Stock Keeping Unit` code, a `string`, it's stored in a separate database table connected by the foreign key `inventory_id`, so yes it is a value of a column inside the `InventorySku` model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hang on, figured it out, apologies!

Eloquent relationships have a method `getRelated()` to access the related model instance. I can then call the methods I need off of it, for example:

```
public static function findBySku($sku)
{
    $instance = new static;

    // Using the getRelated() method allows me to run queries on the related model
    $results = $instance->sku()->getRelated()->get();

    dd($results);
}
```

Just sort of an odd workaround as you'd think accessing the relationship itself would give you the proper query.

I hope this helps out someone in the future!